# pygame No available audio device

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, ubuntu-20.04

I code on Ubuntu 20.04LTS with python 3.8.2 and in my game, I want to put music, so I use this:

```
pygame.mixer.init()
music = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join(current_path,'something.mp3'))
music.play()
```

But I receive this error:

```
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.error: No available audio device
```

What I have to do?

Answer (score 2):

A common problem is selecting the right sound device, if more than one i present.

to list devices:

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
```

It could look like this:

```
 0 [CUBE           ]: USB-Audio - Audiotrak ProDigy CUBE GYROCOM C&C Co., LTD Audiotrak ProDigy CUBE at usb-0000:04:00.0-2, full speed
 1 [IM             ]: USB-Audio - VF0530 Live! Cam Chat IM Creative Labs VF0530 Live! Cam Chat IM at usb-0000:04:00.0-1, high speed
 2 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI HDMI HDA ATI HDMI at 0xf7e60000 irq 45
```

Then you must edit the **~/.asoundrc** to use the right device.
If you want to use device 0, set that value for pcm card:

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 0
}
ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 0
}
```

Also make sure the following libs are installed and configured:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev
sudo sdl-config --cflags --libs
```